# Dropdown box not showing Array in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, google-chrome-extension, dropdownbox

I'm using an array in order to populate a dropdown box.

I want to have the dropdown box working in a chrome extension I'm building - i.e contents of the dropdown are populated by the array.

I'm running into an issue where the chrome extension does not seem to display the array in the dropdown box, however, if I run the file as a regular HTML page (not a browser extension) the dropdown box works as intended.

*First image is of the file run as a html page

- [image]

*Second image is of the same file being run as a chrome extension (no options available in the dropdown) - [image]

The array = 0,1,2,3,4,5

***HTML***

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <select id="dropBox" onchange="getValue()"></select>
</div><br><br>
```

***JS***

```
var dropBox = document.getElementById("dropBox");
var locales = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
for (var i=0; i<locales.length; i++){
    dropBox.options.add(new Option(locales[i]));
}

function getValue(){
    var drop_val = dropBox.options[dropBox.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(drop_val);
}
```

Comment: You cannot use inline JavaScript in chrome extensions (i.e. `onchange="getVAlue()"`). Move all your code to the JS file, something like `dropBox.onchange = getValue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a listener for onchange on the select-element instead of calling an inline Javascript-function from your HTML-file.

```js
var dropBox = document.getElementById("dropBox");
dropBox.onchange = getValue

var locales = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
for(var i in locales) {
    dropBox.add(new Option(locales[i]));
}

function getValue(e){
    var drop_val = e.target.value;
    // Do whatever you would like to do with 'drop_val'
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <select id="dropBox"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for HTML but not for Extension

Comment: Isn't this answer my comment?